# shell command in python to run a specific windows executable

Tags: python

I have been searching but I am so confused. I so appologize if this has been answered before but I have looked and I am even more confused. All I want to do is run an executable file from a python script.

I know to open notepad.exe (for instance) you do the following.

```
#opens notepad in windows
import os
print os.system('notepad.exe')
```

but what if I want to run something specific in a directory

How can I effectively run something like this (this is obviously going to fail)

```
#opens program in windows
import os
print os.system('c:\files\program.exe')
```

the more I read about it, the more confused I get.

I have been reading about sys.executable as well as surprocess but its confusing me more than helping. Could someone clarify how this can be done? An example, perhaps to run a "program.exe" file?

Comment: Fist thing is to make your path to the executable valid. Using backslashes in path is readable in code, but the real string in Python is using it as escacpe character. So you shall either use forward slashes (I recommend it even for Windows), or using "\\" instead of "\"

Comment: or the `r` literal flag ...

Comment: it's subprocess*, btw. that might clear up *some* of the confusion

Comment: @bernie what are you talking about? subprocess is another way (arguably better, although slightly more complicated) to accomplish what OP is asking

Comment: @JoranBeasley: OP misspelled

Comment: ahh I got it now ... lol I doubt that was part of the confusion

Answer (score 3):

You can use `os.system` like that. Note that strings require proper escaping though, so you might need to escape those backslash characters. Alternatively, you can also use a raw string to make it work:

```
os.system(r'c:\files\program.exe')
```

Comment: although to be honest python always understands linux style paths, and I would recommend that ... but meh +1

Comment: @JoranBeasley I personally prefer to use the system’s native path separators. That’s what `os.path.join` uses and why `os.sep` exists. Also you won’t end up mixing the separators when using it, for example, as arguments to programs that do not support any separator.

Comment: @poke the downside is if you store them somewhere that is accessed by various machines or hardcode them into the program or something ... windows slashes only work in windows(afaik ... I might be wrong) while linux paths work in python regardless of OS

Comment: @JoranBeasley Something called `program.exe` will rarely work on non-Windows machines though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use subprocess module https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('c:\files\program.exe')
```

Comment: If `os.system` fails with the path, it will fail with `subprocess.call` too.